# Replace multiple text in string

Tags: php

I have a PHP string of text in a variable that's separated by ^.

E.g.

```
$group = "group1^group2^group3^group4";
```

I want to replace the text so that it looks like the following:

```
$new_group = "Group 1,Group 2,Group 3,Group 4";
```

The complexity is that the variable could be any combination.

E.g.

```
$group = "group2^group4";
```

Which would be:

```
$new_group = "Group 2,Group 4";
```

I have no idea how I can achieve this so would appreciate any help.

Many thanks,

John

Comment: Sometimes you have a space between group and digit, sometimes not. What‘s the rule there, when do you want the space?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. You need to provide us with your attempt, example data, expected results and what results you're currently getting.

Comment: @carambia - Sorry, typo's on my part.

Comment: The format of the string (the "group" word) is always the same?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "group1^group2^group3^group4";

// split by ^
$ar = explode('^', $str);
// capitalize the first letter and add space before the last digits
foreach($ar as &$x) {
    $x = preg_replace('~\d+$~', ' $0',ucfirst($x));
}
// join  
echo implode(', ', $ar);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2134e4d335bb1e429f54fb450ff7161cf1143aa)

Answer (score 0):

I actually just got this working after playing around with it for ages, using the following:

```
$group = "group1^group2^group3^group4";
$new_group = str_replace(array('group1','group2','group3','group4'), array('Group 1','Group 2','Group 3','Group 4'), $group);
echo str_replace("^",",",$new_group);
```

Thanks for replying.